# Type inference failed in the call to 'SelectMany'

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4

I have this LINQ query:

```
        var businessAffiliates = from b in context.Businesses
                                 from ba in b.BusinessOfficers
                                 from p in ba.Person                                     
                                 select b;
```

but I am getting this error:

> An expression of type
>   'myproj.Models.Person' is not allowed
>   in a subsequent from clause in a query
>   expression with source type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable'.
>   Type inference failed in the call to
>   'SelectMany'.

Comment: The query appears incomplete, can you include the rest of it? If this is all of it, why the extra `from` clauses?

Comment: What is the point of this query? How it differs from `var query = context.Businesses`?

Comment: state what you actually want to happen and not only the error you're getting. I have an idea, but I'd rather not engage in psychic debugging, and if your question is to help other people on the internet, they should be able to *find* it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It looks like ba.Person it a single object, but the `from` clause expects a sequence of objects. 
if you replace that line with `let p = ba.Person` then it would work. But i wonder why you need those additional `from` clauses.