# Flatten complex model

Tags: c#, model, linq-to-objects, complextype

I have a nested object with the structure like so: Model A contains a list of Model B. I am wondering if there is a quick way to flatten it.

Example:

```
public class Customer
{
public int ID {get; set;}
public string Name {get; set;}
public List<int> OrderNumber { get; set; }
}
```

This give me a flatten list of only the OrderNumber

```
var list = customerList.Select(x => new { x.ID, x.Name, x.OrderNumber}).Where(x => x.OrderNumber!= null).SelectMany(s => s.OrderNumber).ToList();
```

This give me a list of customer info which contain a list of OrderNumber for each customer record

```
var list = customerList.Select(x => new { x.ID, x.Name, x.OrderNumber}).ToList();
```

I'm looking for a quick way to return a flatten list of customer info a long with flatten list of ordernumber as a string. Something like this...

ID---Name----     OrderNumber

123    JohnDoe   1, 2, 3

564    JaneDoe   1,2

I feel like using the LINQ SelectMany could do the job but not sure how to do it right. As shown above I got the result I want and I just need a way to put it together in one statement. I know I could do a loop and construct a new list to get what I want. It's not the end of the world, but I wanted to learn more about LINQ. Any tips would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I always find this kind of thing easier in query syntax, try this:

```
var query = from cust in customerList
            from orderNo in cust.OrderNumber
            select new { cust.ID, cust.Name, OrderNumber = orderNo };
```

UPDATE

Further to your comments, if you just want the order numbers to be a comma seperated string as the last column you can do the following:

```
var query = customerList.Select(x => new{ x.ID, x.Name, OrderNos = string.Join(",", x.OrderNumber)});
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Thanks for looking into this. I just realized made an error in my post. Let me update it.

Comment: @NKD If you can explain in what way it doesn't work, I may be able to correct it.

Comment: @NKD I have modified the query to match your updated customer class.

Comment: Post updated. Sorry about that. I made a slight change to my code because we had a requirement change from a dropdown to multiselect.  And I have to do a List<int> ordernumber to collect a list of selected order number from the UI.

Comment: it doesn't work because customerList is a list of customer model (List<customer>), it throws back and error on the second 'from' saying it's not allowed because the cust.ordernumber is a list of int. I can get you an exact error message if you like.

Comment: Here you go. I don't know how to attach a screenshot to a comment so I type it. It occurs at cust.OrderNumber (red underline)      Error: An expression of type 'System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' is not allowed in a subsequent from clause in a query expression with source type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumberable<ExampleProject.Model.Customer>'. Type inference failed in the call to 'SelectMany'.

Comment: I am afraid I don't know what that error means, you can see the query working here, perhaps you can work out what the difference is. https://dotnetfiddle.net/fDNdMw

Comment: Thank you for the effort. And thank you for the fiddle. I have been using jsfiddle. I wasn't aware of this .netfiddle. Your output is a little different from what I'm looking for. Ideally it should return 2 records (base on your example), the order number should appears as a string in the last column as "1, 2, 3, 4" in a row instead of multiple rows. I made a small edit to your code here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/elIVjx (doesn't work tho). As for the error earlier. I researched and found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049155/type-inference-failed-in-the-call-to-selectmany