# The type of the expression in the from clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'SelectMany'

Tags: c#, linq

```
using (RPasEntities entities = new RPasEntities())
        {
            response = (from ent in entities.Settings
                        join own in entities.Settings on ent.SystemSettID equals own.MySett
                           into RightTable1
                        from doce1 in RightTable1.DefaultIfEmpty
                        join doc in entities.AllDocuments on ent.SystemSettID equals doc.SystemSettID
                            into RightTableResults
                        from doce in RightTableResults.DefaultIfEmpty
                        where doce1.SystemSettID = userSettingID
                        select new UserViewModel { ID = doce1.SystemSettID, UserName = doce1.UserName == null ? " " : doce1.UserName, MyPassword = doce1.MyPassword, FirstName = doce1.FirstName, LastName = doce1.LastName, SettingName = doce1.SettingName, MySett = doce1.MySett, SettingOwner = doce1.FirstName == null ? " " : doce1.FirstName & " " & doce1.LastName & "(" & doce1.UserName & ")", MyCreator = doce1.MyCreator, MyType = doce1.MyType, Email = doce1.Email, Phone = doce1.Phone, Address = doce1.Address, MyCity = doce1.MyCity, MyState = doce1.MyState, MyZip = doce1.MyZip, Country = doce1.Country, Status = doce1.Status, MyPlan = doce1.MyPlan, CreatedOn = doce1.CreatedOn, TypeLicense = doce.TypeLicense, AuthorizingState = doce.AuthorizingState, NameLicensing = doce.NameLicensing, LicenseNumber = doce.LicenseNumber, LicenseExpiration = doce.LicenseExpiration, LicenseURL = doce.LicenseURL, AdvancedDegree = doce.AdvancedDegree, MajorAreaDegree = doce.MajorAreaDegree, YearDegree = doce.YearDegree, InstitutionDegree = doce.InstitutionDegree, ListPsychometrics = doce.ListPsychometrics, ListInterpret = doce.ListInterpret, ListTraining = doce.ListTraining, ListRor = doce.ListRor, CourseTitle = doce.CourseTitle, CourseNumber = doce.CourseNumber, CourseUniversity = doce.CourseUniversity, CourseDepartment = doce.CourseDepartment, CourseURL = doce.CourseURL, CourseEnrollment = doce.CourseEnrollment, CourseProtocols = doce.CourseProtocols, CourseDirectorName = doce.CourseDirectorName, CourseDirectorEmail = doce.CourseDirectorEmail, ProjectTitle = doce.ProjectTitle, ProjectUniversity = doce.ProjectUniversity, ProjectDepartment = doce.ProjectDepartment, ProjectSupervisorName = doce.ProjectSupervisorName, ProjectSupervisorEmail = doce.ProjectSupervisorEmail, ProjectURL = doce.ProjectURL, ProjectSample = doce.ProjectSample, ProjectCompletion = doce.ProjectCompletion, ProjectVenue = doce.ProjectVenue, CanUse = doce.CanUse }).FirstOrDefault();


        }
        return response;
```

I am Converting Vb.Net Code to C#.Net but in this Code i facing this Problem 
in the 6th Line "from doce1 in RightTable.DefaultIfEmpty" in this line from is giving error . as show in the image  below

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049155/type-inference-failed-in-the-call-to-selectmany

Comment: Shouldn't there be () after "DefaultIfEmpty"?